# Gradle Compiles via Command Line but not Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle

I have a Gradle project, and it compiles if I use `gradle build` directly. Everything works, all the tasks are executed successfully, etc.

But when I hit run in VS Code, it throws out the following error:

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\Person\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\redhat.java\1.16.0\config_win\org.eclipse.osgi\53\0\.cp\gradle\init\init.gradle' (C:\Users\Person\.gradle\caches\7.4.2\scripts\7s4n1zerenary6wu67e7f3xej).
Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\Person\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\redhat.java\1.16.0\config_win\org.eclipse.osgi\53\0\.cp\gradle\init\init.gradle'.
startup failed:
General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 63
```

Major version 63 corresponds to Java 19, and Java 19 is returned by `java -version` and on the path correctly. And, obviously, there's no problem with building it directly.

To make it extra strange, the project then runs despite the build failure (probably because it's already compiled).

Comment: your vscode seems to use a different java version to run your code. Can you verify that in the settings?

Comment: Hm, the only thing I can see is by looking at the Java projects section in the explorer, and it says JRE System Library [JavaSE-19] there.

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of Gradle that supports Java 19. Alternatively, you can downgrade your system's Java version to a version that is compatible with Gradle 7.4.2, such as Java 17.

Comment: That explains why it works on the command line, the system version is 8.0.2. What I'm _not_ following is why it keeps pulling in 7.4.2 when the file specifies Java 19, and the wrapper properties specifies 8.0.2. I've cleaned out all gradle files from the directory and it's _still_ pulling 7.4.2.

Comment: Well, I thought it was due to the Gradle extension in VS Code not supporting Java 19, but the prerelease version does and _that_ keeps trying to use 7.4.2. Odd.

Comment: Install a newer version of Gradle globally.

Comment: The global install was already the latest version. I'm not sure why it was being so uncooperative, but I wound up falling back to 7.4.2 and Java 17.

Comment: I think the problem with doing that here is that it isn't really a solution--it's the obvious workaround, but it won't help if you need to use any of those versions for some reason.

Comment: If you have the full error log and how to reproduce it, you can [report it on GitHub](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/new) to get a developer response.